Condition for a functor to induce a cartesian closed functor between categories of presheaves
We denote the category of presheaves on a small category ${\cal C}$ (set-valued functor-category) by $$\widehat{\cal C}:=[{\cal C}^{op},{\bf Set}].$$
Such a category   is  cartesian closed, i.e. it has a terminal object $T$, any two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\widehat{\cal C}$ have a product
$X\times Y$ in $\widehat{\cal C}$ and any two objects $Y$ and $Z$ have an exponential $Z^Y$ in $\widehat{\cal C}$ with natural bijections
$$\widehat{\cal C}(X\times Y, Z)\cong \widehat{\cal C}(X,Z^Y).$$
Let $F\colon {\cal C}^{op} \to {\cal D}^{op}$ be any functor between small categories and
$$F^\ast\colon [{\cal D}^{op},{\bf Set}] \to [{\cal C}^{op},{\bf Set} ]$$ the induced functor, given by precomposition with $F$.
Question: Under which exact conditions on $F$ is its induced functor $F^\ast$  cartesian closed, i.e. such that the natural comparison morphism
$$\gamma_{X,Y}\colon F^{\ast}(Y^X)\to F^{\ast}(Y)^{F^\ast(X)}$$
is an isomorphism for all objects $X$ and $Y$ of $[{\cal D}^{op},{\bf Set}] $.
In more details: Thanks to the fact, that $F^{\ast}$ preserves products, since it has the left Kan-extension ${\rm Lan}_{F}\colon [{\cal C}^{op},{\bf Set} ] \to [{\cal D}^{op},{\bf Set}] $ as a left adjoint,
we can form the morphism
$$F^\ast(Y^X)\times F^\ast(X) \cong F^{\ast}(Y^X\times X)\stackrel{F^{\ast}({\rm ev})}{\longrightarrow} F^{\ast}(Y),$$
which has the morphism
$$\gamma_{X,Y}\colon F^{\ast}(Y^X)\to F^{\ast}(Y)^{F^\ast(X)}$$
in question as an adjoint.

Here is an observation you already almost made: since $F^*$ has a left adjoint $F_!$ given by left Kan extension, $F^*$ preserves exponential objects if and only if $F_!$ preserves products.
Note that $F_!$ is given by an unwieldy colimit so this does not always happen. Here is however a natural condition which should make it work: in $\mathrm{Set}$, finite products commute with sifted colimits (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sifted+colimit), so if you can guarantee that all the indexing categories of the colimit defining the left Kan extension are sifted, $F_!$ will preserve products.
In particular, categories with finite products are cosifted (and this plays nicely with the $\mathrm{op}$ of presheaves) so that if $F$ is a product-preserving functor between categories with finite products, $F^*$ preserves exponential objects.

An alternative way of seeing why this case works: Products in a presheaf category preserve colimits in each variable (as it’s a left adjoint); so for any $F : C \to D$, to check $F_!$ preserves them, it’s enough to know it preserves products of representables.  But the yoneda embedding preserves whatever limits exist; so if $C$ has finite products and $F : C \to D$ preserves them, then $F_!$ preserves products of representables.
